# More than one value in the same row MYSQL

Tags: mysql

my problem is the next:

I have a sql query that shows information about a booking. The info is the name of the person who made the reservation, phone, etc and the extras he bought. 
I need to show all the extras he bought on the same row but i cant find a method for it (im not very good at mysql)

So, i have two tables : 1 for the general info of the booking and another for the extras info because one reservation can have more than one extra and one extra could be on more than one reservation.

Table booking:
id,name,telephone

table booking_extra:
id, id_extra, id_booking

i want to

```
select * from booking
left join booking_extra on id_booking = booking.id
```

and the result should be something like

```
    id:1
    name: test
    telephone: 123456
    extras: 1,2,3
```

any ideas?

Comment: `group_concat`?

Comment: almost! but it shows me just one row with all the extras, i need to show all the reservations, not just one...

Comment: How did not find group_concat when googling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @panther hinted in the comment, use `group_concat`. So you query will be like:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.TELEPHONE, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.ID_EXTRA ORDER BY B.ID_EXTRA ASC SEPARATOR ',') EXTRAS
FROM BOOKING A LEFT JOIN BOOKING_EXTRA B ON A.ID=B.ID_BOOKING
GROUP BY A.ID, B.ID_BOOKING;
```

Comment: where is the group condition?

Comment: Hi @krishnaaryal, thanks very much for commenting. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
SELECT id, name, telephone, GROUP_CONCAT(extras, separator ',')
FROM booking
LEFT JOIN booking_extra ON id_booking = booking.id
GROUP BY id, name, telephone
```

Comment: then why did you chose the other answer ? :'(

Comment: the 'distinc' condition, sorry!